# Why I have to configure bean ResourceBundleMessageSource to use MessageSource

Tags: java, spring

I don't understand why I have to create bean `ResourceBundleMessageSource`,

```
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename("i18n/messages");
    return source;
}
```

to use in my class `MessageSource` interface?

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

Can you explain me where is the link between `ResourceBundleMessageSource` and `MessageSource`?

Please provide me information about how can I check it in Spring code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessageSource` is an Interface so it's spring way to use more common contract rather than implementation.

`ResourceBundleMessageSource` is an implementation of the MessageSource interface.

`MessageSource` is wider and can include other message sources not only the `ResourceBundleMessageSource`

Thus you add your own message source but use another one which may include aggregated message sources as well.

You can set a breakpoint and check what is real class assigned to the

```
private MessageSource messageSource
```

it's not necessary your `ResourceBundleMessageSource`